# How can I sort a list of lists by making the first row match another list?

Tags: python, list

I want to sort a list of lists ie:

```
[['Y', 'K', 'E'],
 [3, 1, 2],
 [6, 4, 5]]
```

The first row of that list should match another supplied list (this list will always containing matching letters to the first row of the first list):

```
['K', 'E', 'Y']
```

So that the final output is:

```
[['K', 'E', 'Y'],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: I'm confused. How do you want to sort? Based on the second row? Based on the third row?

Comment: @erip he wants to sort in order of supplied list

Comment: @PaulRooney I tried sorting it using lambdas but ive been getting errors with matching it up

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easy way is to transpose it with `zip()`, sort it with a key of the first element's index in the key list, then transpose it back:

```
>>> data = [['Y', 'K', 'E'],
...  [3, 1, 2],
...  [6, 4, 5]]
>>> key = 'KEY'
>>> sorted(zip(*data), key=lambda x: key.index(x[0]))
[('K', 1, 4), ('E', 2, 5), ('Y', 3, 6)]
>>> list(zip(*sorted(zip(*data), key=lambda x: key.index(x[0]))))
[('K', 'E', 'Y'), (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: Nice solution. I was going to do something similar. +1

Comment: I found this not to work when I used chars instead of ints in the data[1/2] list, anyway around that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

A pretty straightforward approach using list comprehensions:

```
>>> L = [['Y', 'K', 'E'], [3, 1, 2], [6, 4, 5]]
>>> indexes = [L[0].index(x) for x in "KEY"]
>>> [[row[i] for i in indexes] for row in L]
[['K', 'E', 'Y'], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```